# How to show alert message while typing particular character like Enter key or Esc key in CKEditor using Javascript/C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ckeditor

```
<script  type = "text/javascript">
    var text = document.getElementById("CKEditor1");

    window.addEventListener("keydown", alert, false);

    functionalert(event) {
        var x = event.keyCode;
        console.log(x);

        if (x == 13) {
            //alert pressed enter key
        }
        else if (x ==35) {
            //presses space bar
        }
    }
</script>
```

It's not working. If anybody have idea please share. Show alert message while typing particular character like Enter key or `Esc` key in `CKEditor` using Javascript/C#

Comment: alert("I am an alert box!"); :)

Comment: no its not working!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code for key event on ckeditor.

Lets say or ckeditor instance id is `'CKEditor1'`

```
var ckeditor = CKEDITOR.instances['CKEditor1'];
ckeditor.on('key' , function(event) {
  var x = event.data.keyCode;
  console.log(x);

  if (x == 13) {
    //alert pressed enter key
    alert("pressed enter key");
  }
  else if (x ==32) {
    //presses space bar
    alert("pressed space bar");
  }
});
```

Please check working demo : https://jsfiddle.net/rbua57pq/1/

Comment: @sun please check the updated answer. I have shared a working demo as well in it.

Comment: @sun Very happy that it helped you. Please accept and upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var text = document.getElementById("CKEditor1");

 window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
     var x = event.keyCode;
     console.log(x);

     if (x == 13) {
        alert('Esc pressed!');
     }
     else if (x ==35) {
        alert('space bar pressed!');
     }
 });
```

Try this.